# What's the point of buying books?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In Revelations there are bookstores sprinkled around the map. You can buy treasure maps at bookstores - very useful. You can also buy books at bookstores - less useful, I think. Is there any reason to collect books (other than the simple pursuit of 100%)?

Comment: If you go to the hideout and "investigate" a book, you will get a short description. Just like there were short descriptions about the paintings in AC 2 - a mini lesson in art history.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are kind of like the paintings from Assassin's Creed II and Brotherhood: there is no real in-game point to them beyond filling up a room at the hideout. You can't read them or interact with them in any way other than getting some information about the book and its author.

You do get an achievement for buying all the books from every city and doing the Niccolo Polo book missions, but that's about it.

Comment: Just want to point out too that you will need to go to the Cappadocia, to get 3 books there for 350k if you want the acheivement.

Comment: Paintings in Assassin's Creed II **did** have a purpose - they increased the value of your city.

Comment: @Shinrai As in, added to the income? Man, I've been missing out on an income source then. :)

Comment: Yes; they were actually worth a fairly good chunk of cash.  They didn't do anything in AC:B, though.

Comment: @Shinrai I thought I remembered them being useful! I'm not big on getting All The Achievements but I did remember buying paintings in ACII. I knew there must have been a reason I did that!

Comment: When you are buying them, it says something like "[assassin's logo] -15%". Does that mean anything?

Comment: @Kip those logos mean that when you're buying any item in an Assassin-controlled area, you get 15% off the price you'd pay if you were buying them in a Templar-controlled area (like Cappadocia). See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40246/what-does-the-a-15-statistic-mean-when-shopping-for-armor).

Comment: I'm not even sure collecting them gives you an achievement - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48090