# What does the "A -15%" statistic mean when shopping for armor?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I was shopping for some armor last night, and I noticed a statistic on the armor purchase screen that I hadn't seen in previous AC games.  It looked like the "Assassin's Logo" (a stylized A of sorts) followed by "-15%".  What is this for?

I didn't notice it on the armor/inventory equip screens after I'd purchased it.  My best guess is it's some sort of discount for being an Assassin.  I could see why you might want to give a guy who has robes full of pointy things a discount, but why 15%?  If it is a discount, how can I get a *bigger* one?

Comment: The stylized "A" replaces the "f" symbol from previous games in regards to money, because you aren't spending florins anymore. :)

Comment: Specifically, the stylized A stands for Akçe, the currency of the area at the time.

Comment: That's actually a *different* stylized A.  The one I'm speaking of is actually the Assassin's logo (sort of an inverted, stylized V shape moreso than the symbol for the currency in this game)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Owning the shop, you get 15% reduction on the prices of items. When you get to cappadoce, everything costs 15% more because they are under control of the templars.

Comment: To clarify, the "A" indicates assassin control of the area.

Comment: When an Assassin's den is attacked by Templars and they "control the area", then all the stores in that area will have the Templars logo and a +15% just as in Cappadoce.

Comment: Are there any shops you can buy things from that you *don't* own? Doesn't that make it a pointless distinction?

Comment: Yes. Read comment from Ilya just before yours.