# In Assassin's Creed Revelation what does the assassin symbol - x% mean on books

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the “A -15%” statistic mean when shopping for armor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40246/what-does-the-a-15-statistic-mean-when-shopping-for-armor)

Every book you can buy (and i think other items as well) has an assassin's symbol and a -percentage. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That symbol relates to the amount of influence your takeover of the city is affecting a discounted price at that particular store. If you've removed all of the Templar towers/Templar influence for that region, your discount will be even higher.

The only exception to this is in Cappadocia, where you are unable to remove Templar influence, resulting in a drastic *mark-up* on all prices.