# Is there any benefit to collecting books?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of buying books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38899/whats-the-point-of-buying-books)

Once I found the first hidden book, a bunch more book icons popped up on my radar.  What use is collecting books?  I know that there's an achievement for getting all of them, and I get a few coins for grabbing them, but is there any other effect on the game for finding more of them before I finish the game?

Comment: Ah, I read the title and thought that question just covered book shopping, and not book finding.  My apologies if that's the consensus.

Comment: Yeah, the books you find work out exactly like the books you buy, no real use other than achievements and getting 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ezio must find certain sets of hidden books to unlock the locations of the Masyaf keys hidden around Istanbul.