# Is the "Sage" (get all books) achievement broken in AC:R?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, assassins-creed-revelations

I have completed every book quest, renovated every book shop and bought every book they have. I've also gone back to Cappadocia by replaying memory 7-2 and bought all the books there.

I still don't have the "Sage" achievement - the description is *Collect all available books* so it seems like I should.

Am I missing something? If so then what?

Is this achievement broken? If so then is there any way to fix it?

It seems odd that a triple-A title like AC:R would have a bug that makes it impossible to complete it.

Comment: It seems to be a problem on the PS3 as well, just so you know...

Comment: This has now been patched, on the Xbox at least :-) Unfortunately just as they've added a load more new achievements for as-yet unreleased DLC, so still uncomplete-able.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sage trophy/achievement was apparently broken in update 1.02, see later comments [here](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/assassins-creed-revelations/trophy/38764-Sage.html) and [this](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/assassins-creed-revelations/139462-i-believe-1-02-bugged-sage-trophy-banks-revanue.html) forum post.

There are currently no workaround aside from deleting the game data and trying to trigger the trophy again, either by loading a save where you don't have all the books and collecting them all or by attempting this on a fresh save. Hopefully a patch will be available soon which will fix this.

Comment: So complete the entire game and buy all books, from scratch, offline, after deleting all updates? Laaaame.

Comment: Or, wait for this to (hopefully) be patched. However, it's still possible that a future patch will require you to replay the game.